# flex: list of files

Tags: apache-flex, file, list, mobile

I'm making a Flex mobile application with Flash Builder 4.6 And I have a question for a function I want to implement.

I have a declaration:

```
<s:HTTPService id="getXMLFile" fault="trace('No CCR found!')" result="getPatient(event)"
                       resultFormat="object" url="assets/CCR1.xml"/>
```

But this only points to one file and this has to be typed in.
Already now how to change the url and do the request again.

```
getXMLFile.url = "assets/CCR2.xml";
getXMLFile.send();
```

But I want to have some sort of function to check all the files in the "assets" package and to this code part for each file. So I want something like this:

```
for(var file:string in assets) {
getXMLFile.url = "assets/" + file;
getXMLFile.send();
}
```

Thx

Comment: As far as I know, there is no tools for this in actionscript. You need to specify filenames in some variable(Array) to dot this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;



        //Create one xml having all URL, which you can parse on Flex side. Collect all URL in Array (ex:- fileArray), 
        //than you can loop it. You can call parseXML on creationComplete of your application.
        private var fileArray:Array = new Array();
        private var count:int = 0;

        //Collect all URL in this fileArray.
        private function parseXML():void
        {
            //parse XML and puch URL in fileArray
            // xmlLength var is xml length.
            var xmlLength:int;
            for(var i:int;i<xmlLength ;i++)
            {
                var URL:String = "";
                //URL = parse Value from XML; 
                fileArray.push(URL);
            }
            sendRequest();
        }

        private function sendRequest():void
        {
            getXMLFile.url = fileArray (count);
            getXMLFile.send();
        }

        private function getPatient(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            //If Success request for Next Patient
            requestForNextPatient();
        }

        private function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            //If fault request for Next Patient 
            requestForNextPatient();
        }

        private function requestForNextPatient():void
        {
            //Request for Next Patient
            count++;
            if(count > fileArray.length)
                sendRequest():
        }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:HTTPService id="getXMLFile" fault="faultHandler(event)" result="getPatient(event)" resultFormat="object" />
```

This may help you.....